# c# String to Integer to DateTime ISO Format

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I am a bit lost and need your help, this seems to be easy in PHP but I am new to C#.

I have a string

```
string str = "41305"; // equivalent to 01/31/2013, parse from excel reader.
```

I need to insert date in DBF file and I am getting mismatch data type.
How can I format it to DateTime ISO Format 20130131? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) method.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(41305);
```

For output:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyyy"));
```

Output would be:

```
01/31/02013
```

Since you have the value in string, you can parse it to double using `Double.Parse` or `Double.TryParse` according to your requirement.

EDIT: Like:

```
string str = "41305";
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(str));
```

Comment: @MatthewWatson, yes just noted that down as well, actually `int.Parse` is fine, but the method `DateTime.FromOADate` accepts `double` type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "41305"; 
DateTime d = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(str));
```